# Can I combine two bindings?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to update a widgets on a canvas widget when the window is resized. You can bind a function call on window resize via the `<Configure>` flag:

```
window.bind("<Configure>",resize)
```

However, this calls resize continuously while the window is being updated, many times per second. What would be better is if I could call resize after the window has been resized. So I imagine, once MB1 has been released.

So can I combine bindings? I need to combine both `<Configure>` and `<ButtonRelease-1>`

I was thinking of creating a global variable that contains the state of MB1, and updating this state via `<ButtonRelease-1>` and `<ButtonPress-1>` but I'm wondering if there's a lass hacky method.

Comment: I suppose you could bind a function to `<ButtonPress-1>` that will get the window size before resizing, and then bind `<ButtonRelease-1>` to a function that gets the *new* size used by your `resize` function and adjusts the canvas accordingly

Comment: @JRiggles oh that's a good idea. This is an edge case, but what about people who use the keyboard to resize the window?

Comment: Hmmm...maybe you could do something similar using whatever key bindings are used for resizing using the same "before and after" trick. I'm not sure!

Comment: What exactly are you updating on that widget that needs to be managed in this way? That context might help here in answering your question.

Comment: @JRiggles that 1st part is not needed. Only the button release function should be needed since you can ID window size at any point.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I suppose you're right. The initial window size won't make much of a difference here!

Comment: @JRiggles after some testing the button release does not trigger if you are resizing from the border of the root window even if your bind is on the root window. So Bryans solution below is probably the only real option.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Ah darn. Well thanks for digging into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to not do the work immediately, but instead schedule it for some time in the future. Each time the `<Configure>` event is handled you can cancel any previously scheduled work before scheduling the work again.

The following example shows how to update a label in the middle of a frame on `<Configure>`, but only after the window size hasn't changed for 200ms.

```
import tkinter as tk

def handle_configure(event):
    global after_id
    if after_id:
        event.widget.after_cancel(after_id)
    after_id = event.widget.after(200, update_label)

def update_label():
    width = root.winfo_width()
    height = root.winfo_height()
    text = f"Size: {width}x{height}"
    label.configure(text=text)

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root, width=400, height=400)
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

label = tk.Label(frame, text="")
label.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")

after_id = None
frame.bind("<Configure>", handle_configure)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I was going to use a timer to do this but using `after_cancel()` makes way more since seeing it like this.